# Help on align the equations to the equal sign.

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
$$\begin{array}{rcl} 
\sum_{k=1}^{n}cx_k &= cx_1 + cx_2 + cx_3 + \dots + cx_n \\
                       &= c(x_1+x_2+x_3+ \dots + x_n) \\
                       &= c\sum_{k=1}^{n}cx_k \\
                       &= cs_n \\
                       &\to cL
\end{array}$$
\end{document}
```

I am trying to align those equations to the equal sign, but it comes out horrible like this:

[image]

Comment: Use the advantages of the package `amsmath` which provides the environment `align`. You should also read the mathmode: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode?lang=de

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined a three column array but only used two columns so all your right hand sides were in the second column, so centred.

But you do not want `array` here (and never use `$$` in latex) use an AMS alignment. Apart from aligning properly, it uses display math (see the `\sum`)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}cx_k &= cx_1 + cx_2 + cx_3 + \dots + cx_n \\
                       &= c(x_1+x_2+x_3+ \dots + x_n) \\
                       &= c\sum_{k=1}^{n}cx_k \\
                       &= cs_n \\
                       &\to cL
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It looks much more neat now. But is there anyway I can slide the equations to the far left so $\sum_{k=1}^{n}cx_k$ is right next to the left margin?

Comment: @user3000482 yes that is called flush left equations just add `[fleqn]` to your document class options at the top of the file.

Comment: But wouldn't that make all my equations to go to the left margin? I only want this bunch of equations to slide to the left side. Also, why shouldn't I use $$??

Comment: please don't add followup questions in comments, the site mechanics don't really support that. on `$$` see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/69854#69854

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of variety, here's a solution that replaces the `array` environment in your solution with an `IEEEeqnarray*` environment (from the package [IEEEtrantools](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/tools/)).

Compared with the "look" that's generated with an `align*` environment, the main difference is that all symbols in the middle "column" -- here: `=` and `\to` -- are automatically *centered horizontally* with respect to each other. That's not the case in an `align*` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools} % for 'IEEEeqnarray*' env.
\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}cx_k &=& cx_1 + cx_2 + cx_3 + \cdots + cx_n \\
                   &=& c(x_1+x_2+x_3+ \cdots + x_n) \\
                   &=& c\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k \\
                   &=& cs_n \\
                   &\to& cL
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```